# how to encode json array from mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=DB1;', 'user1','123456');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM events';
$out = array();
foreach($db->query($sql) as $row) {
$out[] = array(
'id' => $row->title,
'title' => $row->name,
'url' => $row->url,
'class' => $row->class,
'start' => $row->start . '000',
'end' => $row->end .'000'
 );
 }

echo json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'result' => $out));
exit;
?>
```

Table Structure

```
Field Type Null Key Default Extra
id int(5) NO NULL
title text NO NULL
url text NO NULL
class text NO NULL
start datetime NO NULL
end datetime NO NULL
```

It displays output as

```
{"success":1,"result":        [{"id":null,"title":null,"url":null,"class":null,"start":"000","end":"000"},    {"id":null,"title":null,"url":null,"class":null,"start":"000","end":"000"}]}
```

i want to print data in tables instead of null

Thank You.

Comment: Are you sure your query is returning something? Try executing the query directly on the database. Also try print the `$row` variable to see its contents

Comment: yes when i execute query it returns values. But i try to use in php it shows null. Here i include my source please help me http://sadakpramodh.esy.es/json_project.zip

Answer (score 0):

You are not querying your rows the proper way.

Instead of :

```
'id' => $row->title,
```

use

```
'id' => $row['title'],
```

for more information, see [example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) in the official documentation

Comment: Thank you for your answer but no change in my output. Here my files are http://sadakpramodh.esy.es/json_project.zip

Comment: what do you have when you do a __var_dump($row)__

Answer (score 0):

not tried this but you could change this:

```
foreach($db->query($sql) as $row) {
```

to

```
foreach($db->query($sql) as (object)$row) {
```

... which might allow the syntax used to access records.

Comment: Thank you RamRaider it doesn't change my output please checkout my project here http://sadakpramodh.esy.es/json_project.zip